# Error saving customer record after publish, doing T300 YogiFon exercise online course

Tags: acumatica

I am doing the T300 Acumatica YogiFon exercise online course. Publish is successful, but on attempting to save the Customer after making changes, I got the error below:

---

### Message from webpage

### [A]PX.Objects.CR.ContactExt cannot be cast to [B]PX.Objects.CR.ContactExt. Type A originates from 'RuntimeCode_1AEBD00CDE079136, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Program Files\Acumatica ERP\Customization\AcumaticaERP\Temp\10f57cd610be4063b2c106062a7f3e47\RuntimeCode_1AEBD00CDE079136.dll'. Type B originates from 'RuntimeCode_1AEBD059B2E07F24, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Program Files\Acumatica ERP\Customization\AcumaticaERP\Temp\10f57cd610be4063b2c106062a7f3e47\RuntimeCode_1AEBD059B2E07F24.dll'.

### OK

I tried "publish with cleanup". But this worked sometimes. After changes here and there, and republishing, it fails again.

Update...

After I restart the whole machine, then it works.

The version I am running is --> 19.111.0038

Answer (score 0):

Training is not up to date and in newer versions of Acumatica there's a conflict with multiple contact DAC extensions. I would advise to skip this part of training.

You can try renaming the DAC or having it in a different namespace but other vexing errors do occur. Not really worth fixing if your goal is just to go through training.